# how to assign a list with lists of lists in python

Tags: python

So here is an example. At the end a[[]] should contain all b lists. Do u need any other details???

```
a [[]]
b[]
n = 0;
for w in g:
b = ["1", "2", "3"]
a[0] = b // now a[0] contains ["1", "2", "3"]
do some changes to b
n += 1
......

next iteration of the loop
b = ["5", "6", "7"]
a[1] = b // now a[1] contains ["5", "6", "7"]
n +=1 (now n is 2)
and so on..


The error I get is - IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Comment: Please provide an example of what you mean; it's very unclear.

Comment: You say you "tried the following" but it's just pseudocode!

Comment: "I have an empty list containing two lists" -- how can an empty list *contain* anything?

Comment: Ferdinand Beyer - this simply means list of lists

Comment: When you say "it doesn't work", what do you mean? Do you get an exception? Does the code run successfully but give the wrong results? Please elaborate (and show some real code!) so we can help you better.

Comment: No no no. Edit in the example, don't replace everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want:

```
a = []
for x in y:
    # stuff happens
    # ...
    a.append(b[:])
```

This will make `a` a list of lists, where each sub-list is a copy of the list `b` from one loop iteration. You can't assign beyond the end of a list, e.g.

```
a = []
a[0] = "foo"
```

Because `a[0]` *doesn't exist* until you `append` to or `extend` the list.

Answer (score 0):

This is a shady attempt, since your OP is extremely vague.

Reading between the lines:

```
while n < len(a):
    for i in b:
        a[n].append(i)
    n += 1
```